# how to get previous versions of cordova in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, apache, cordova, ionic-v1

My app running on a previous version of cordova, but my new colleagues updated to new cordova version, for that my app is not running.

my question is, how can i get my previous version of cordova which i worked?

Comment: The Ionic V1 repo is at https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1

Answer (score 0):

For windows

npm install -g cordova[Version]

ex. npm install -g cordova@7.0.0

For linux/macos

sudo npm install -g cordova@[Version]

ex. sudo npm install -g cordova@7.0.0